# JavaScript setInterval only works once

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I hope you are doing well.
I'm working on a minigame based on JS and want to prevent the user from shooting infinite bullets, so I created this condition. Which only works for the first time and then breaks for the next clicks

also to mention this whole section is inside the loop so shooting works well with or without setInterval

```
  let shootController = true

  canvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (shootController) {
      //shooting code goes here
      shootController = false;
    }
  });

  if (shootController === false) {
    setInterval(() => {
      shootController = true;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Thanks for your replies beforehand

Comment: You never clear the interval?

Comment: Hopefully your real code does not have the syntax error.

Comment: Unclear what you are expecting to happen. The interval is not going to be created since the `shootController` is true. The if statement does not magically keep checking for the state of the variable to use the interval code. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Basically, if the shootController is true so we can draw a shape on the canvas with the first 'if'.   and then the shootController gets false and we can't spam and create more shapes. and I want to wait one second before creating the next shape.    this waiting works fine for the first time but after that, I can spam shapes again @epascarello

Comment: The loop is not interrupted by the timer so shootController become true as soon as the loop is re-entered. Move the `let shootController=true` outside of the loop an it will remain false for the set interval (but looping will continue and probably complete thousands of loops before shootController becomes true again.

Comment: `let shootController=true` is actually outside of any loop and it has only been defined once at the beginning. @DavePritlove

Comment: *"also to mention this whole section is inside the loop"* please modify your question and include sufficient code to reveal the problem

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I defined the 'setInterval' before and outside the loop and then called that function below and outside. This one WORKS

But from curiosity, I didn't define it at the top as a function and only used it below the loop. This one didn't work.

The problem is solved, but I don't know why.